# document.title take text between a tags

Tags: jquery, html

Hard to find a good title but hope this is ok.

I'm now using:

```
document.title = page + ' - ' + originalTitle
```

```html
<a class="menu" id="Home" href="index.php">Home</a>
```

So the result is now `"index - originalTitle"`. But I would change "page" for something like "a id" or just takeover the text between the a tags, for e.g:

```
document.title = a id + ' - ' + originalTitle
```

```html
<a class="menu" id="Home" href="index.php">Home</a>
```

So the result would be `"Home - originalTitle"`

Easy to fix i guess, but hard to find a solution on google or SO

Edit: Let me put the complete code to specify my comment

```
    $(function(){
// part 1
        $('#buttons a, nav a').click(function(){
            location.hash=$(this).attr('href').match(/(^.*)\./)[1]
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
            return false
        })
// part 2
        var originalTitle=document.title
        function hashChange(){
            var page=location.hash.slice(1)
            if (page!=""){
                $('#content').load(page+".php #content")
                document.title = $('#Home').text() + ' - ' + originalTitle
                document.title = $('#Projects').text() + ' - ' + originalTitle
                document.title = $('#About').text() + ' - ' + originalTitle
            }
        }
// part 3
        if ("onhashchange" in window){ // cool browser
            $(window).on('hashchange',hashChange).trigger('hashchange')
        }else{ // lame browser
            var lastHash=''
            setInterval(function(){
                if (lastHash!=location.hash)
                    hashChange()
                lastHash=location.hash
            },100)
        }
    })
```

My nav

```
<div id=buttons">
    <a id="Home" href="index.php">Home</a><span>|</span>
    <a id="Projects" href="Projects.php">Projects</a><span>|</span>
    <a id="About" href="about.php">About</a><span>|</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5, you are able to set custom attributes prefixed with `data-` to elements and get valid HTML:

```
<a href="index.html" data-doc-title="Home">Homepage</a>
```

Using jQuery, you can get the attribute like this:

```
var doc_title = $("a").attr("data-doc-title");
document.title = doc_title + " - " + originalTitle;
```

That way, you can define the title prefix independant from ids and the anchors text value.

Further information about `data-*` attributes can be found [here on W3Schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

---

Edit:
You can access these `data-*` values in vanilla JavaScript quite easy too:

```
<a href="#" id="yourid" data-doc-title="Your Title">Some Text</a>
```

```
var your_element = document.getElementById("yourid");
var doc_title = your_element.datasets.docTitle; // omitting "data-" and dashes are converted to camelCase
// OR
var doc_title = your_element.getAttribute("data-doc-title");
```

Please note: Using the `datasets` attribute is slower than using `getAttribute()` and is not available for Internet Explorer versions older than 11 (use `getAttribute()`instead).

[These `data-*` attributes can be accessed through CSS too, which *can* be an advantage in some use cases.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#CSS_Access)

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: As a user I'd expect the title of the page to change to that of the navigation link I picked, why would you need to use the data prefix? Not trying to bash your implementation just wondering

Comment: Imagine having a link "Back to Gallery" somewhere on the webpage. Abusing the element id for this is not cool, and extracting the title from the link would not produce the wanted results (i guess).

Comment: For links in a navigation you are probably right, @N.J.Dawson.

Comment: Other scenario: Linking a logo (image) in the navigation bar to the website index. In this case, you can't just simply use the text content from the anchor, because there is none.

Comment: Very fleshed outthought process on the matter, for correctness this is definitely the best answer. +1 from me.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson Your implementation is not wrong, so you got the upvote from me. If you have only plain text links in your navbar, then your way (extracting the text) is probably the more efficient way, saving some time and bytes. (if i had the reputation, i would've commented there ;) ).

Comment: This didnt work for me, it says "Undefined" in the titlebar.

Comment: @Jorus Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/516Lqeds/ . Apparently, you have to use `$(event.target)` instead of `$(this)` inside of your `click`-function for your anchors.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but i dont know what you mean actually. Guess its getting to complicated for me lol. document.title = $('#Home').text() + ' - ' + originalTitle this sounds more logic to me, but i cant use it multiple times probably. I dont understand why 'page' is just taking over the pagename as title, and there is no such easy thing to just take the a tag text.

Comment: @Jorus https://gist.github.com/RicoBrase/bc383e045953137517f8a60e06ca4d5f Just have a look into this basic html file containing your modified code (copy it into a local html file and open it in a browser). As you can see, i added a `var doc_title = undefined;` so we have a variable, where we can store our title. In the `click()` function, i've put the part, which gets the `data-*`attribute from the `<a>`element. Finally, in the `hashChange()` funtion, we set the document title to our variable (or nothing, if our variable is empty).
JSFiddle can't handle hash changes. ;)

Comment: Excellent !! Two more things, can you explain why i only see my browsers name after i refresh? And is this method quite SEO friendly?

Comment: @Jorus When you reload the page, the javascript gets executed again, of course, it will use the default title then (html's <title></title>or browser default, if title is not set). On page load, you should check, if a hash is already set and search your links for the first link, that redirects to that hash and get it's data-* attribute. Regarding SEO, you might want to read [this article](https://www.oho.com/blog/explained-60-seconds-hash-symbols-urls-and-seo).

Comment: When i load the page from the beginning there is no hash and the title stays the same after refresh. When i click on a page there's a hash, and when i refresh, the original title is visible for one second and then turns in to browser default.

Comment: @Jorus Ah, i see. The `hashChange()` fucntion gets executed when the site loads, too. Have a look at the line, where `document.title`is set.  Replace the empy quotation marks at the end with your `originalTitle` variable and it should work. That is the fallback, if no link was clicked yet.
I'll update the gist too, to reflect this change.

Comment: That was the trick! Awesome, well done! I had a look about the SEO article, but it was hard to understand. I will google around a bit to see if i can get it in my own language or easier english.

Comment: @Jorus You're welcome. :) A very short summary of the article: Use `#!` (called "hashbang") in the url, instead of `#`. The google crawler then knows, it's ajax loaded content instead of the regular html anchor jumps (different content, so it should get indexed).

Comment: Yeah i did understand that. But in my href i have index.php, so somewhere in the script it add's a hash, but where? Somewhere over here .match(/(^.*)\./)[1] ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122515/discussion-between-jorus-and-ricobrassers).

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the text within the ID and append it to the document title like so:

```
document.title = $('#Home').text() + ' - ' + originalTitle
```

This selects the element with the ID 'home'
    $('#Home')

and

```
.text()
```

would refer to the text within the element.

Comment: Thanks for all the reactions. Is it possible to have multiple document.title's? Because when i do this it doesnt work. My situation is that i use it in combination with ajax .load.